# Get UserManager instance inside IConfigureOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

is it possible to get a custom instance of UserManager inside "Configure" (IConfigureOptions)? When I try to get the instance inside of "Configure" I get the following error inside **ApplicationUserManager** class. Thx!

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.'
```

**My code**

*ConfigureIdentityOptions*

```
public class ConfigureIdentityOptions : IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ConfigureIdentityOptions(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    public void Configure(IdentityOptions identityOptions)
    {
        using (var currentScope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            using (var userManager = currentScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationUserManager>())
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

*ConfigureServices*

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(x =>
        x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    serviceCollection.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureIdentityOptions>();

    serviceCollection.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(x =>
        {
            ...
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
        .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
        .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
        .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .AddRoleManager<ApplicationRoleManager>()
        .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

*ApplicationUserManager*

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber identityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger) :
        base(userStore, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer,
            identityErrorDescriber,
            serviceProvider, logger)
    { }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `IOptions<>` supports anything but a default (empty) constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels wrong to me, to try and do what you are trying to do.  If you want to read configuration from somewhere other than the normal places (appsettings.json, environment etc), then you should be creating a configuration provider (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/index?view=aspnetcore-3.0)), then you can just access the configuration as normal.